# Object Comparison using if else | Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, comparison, operator-overloading

I have to `compare(>,<,==)`  two `class object` based upon different criteria, explained below.

```
class Student
{
    int iRollNumber;
    int iSection;
    int iMarks;
}
```

1. I want to do comparison with `iRollNumber, iSection, iMarks` (Independently).
2. I want to do comparison with `iRollNumber, iSection` (Combined).
3. I want to do comparison with `iMarks, iSection` (Combined).
4. ..........

Currently I am achieving this with `GetMethods()` and comparing them using `if elseif elseif..` structure.

This is leading to the messy code everywhere!

If I use `operator overloading` I have to decide on one way of comparison.

Please suggest a way to do it with elegant coding.

Or

Can it be possible to call operator overloading Polymorphically?

Comment: What is `RoolNumber`?  :P. It should be `RollNumber` :D

Comment: That's your problem (using geter methods (bad OO)).

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? Perhaps a few auxiliary functors (or lambdas) coupled with STL algorithms or containers are all you need, but there's no telling unless you say what you want to use the comparisons for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write named functions:

```
int CompareR( const Student & a, const Student & b );
int CompareS( const Student & a, const Student & b );
int CompareM( const Student & a, const Student & b );
int CompareRS( const Student & a, const Student & b );
int CompareMS( const Student & a, const Student & b );
```

although the need to do so many different kinds of comparison on a class is a bit unusual - you normally only need one or perhaps two. The functions should return the same kind of values as strcmp() does:

```
<  returns -1
== returns 0
>  returns 1
```

Comment: @Neil: Don't think too much outside of the box, your brain will fall down :P  .... (+1 by the way :D).

Comment: @Nawaz I don't think you can get much further inside the box than this! It's not even "really" C++, use of references aside.

Comment: Why not follow the lead of C++ and just define a boolean function that does less than (multiple ways). The other variants are easily defined in terms of this.

Comment: @Martin Because you *do* have to define them - it's more work, more code. And this is the way that C++ does it - ever used std::string::compare?